# C++ winsock recvfrom() and sendto()

Tags: c++, udp, winsock

I have a client application using winsock's `sendto()` method to send data to a server application with UDP. On my client application I make, say, 5 quick `sendto()`. On my server application, I wait for, say, 10 secs, and then do a `select()` and `recvfrom()`. Will the `recvfrom()` give me the first packet sent by the client or will it be an arbitrary one (whichever one arrived first)? Will I still be able to get the other 4 data packets or does winsock's UDP framework only buffer one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP gives no guarantee to the received ordering of packets, so basically, the first packet you `recvfrom()` *might* be the first packet you sent, but must not be - that's what TCP is for (which guarantees ordering of received data). You might not receive a part of the packets (or any, for that matter) at all if they were lost in transit.

For the second part: generally, the operating system will buffer a certain amount of packets for you, this depends on the socket buffer set up for UDP sockets - the buffer is specific to every socket, and not shared between them. On Windows, I'm not sure at how to get at the size of the buffer, on Linux, check out "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/udp_mem"; generally, you'll easily fit five UDP packets in there.

Comment: Can the `recvfrom()` return the same packet twice, even if it was sent just once?

Comment: Yes, packet duplication can happen in transit. With UDP, all bets are off wrt. reliability.

Answer (score 2):

> Will the recvfrom() give me the first packet sent by the client or
>   will it be an arbitrary one

Since UDP doesn't handle reordering, you can get any of the messages. You could get less than 4 messages or even more (but that's rare today).

Answer (score 1):

With 5 packets of reasonable size, you will *probably* get all of the packets and you will *probably* get the first one sent first.  But they might be out of order, might not arrive, and might not contain the original data if they do arrive.  You have to handle all of that yourself with UDP.  (But depending on your application and requirements and the stability of your network, it might not be a real problem; it is certainly possible for certain situations to exist where receiving 99% of the data is perfectly fine).

Comment: Although it's very likely that at least the data will be correct, since UDP has some primitive checksumming built-in.

Comment: If the source host has UDP checksumming enabled - hosts may choose not to use UDP checksumming on the sending side.